# i need to use GET method for my custom Object,but not able to use it

Tags: rest-api, integration, apexrest, workbench

I am using GET to fetch Primary_subscription__c object

I am not able to use this custom objct in URI

```
/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/**Primary_subscription__c**/0010l00000dd2
```

Please suggest..

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid 15- or 18-character Id, and if it were, it'd be an Account Id. Make sure you're using a valid 15- or 18-character Id. You should have an Id that starts with a lowercase "a" for your custom object record. If you're trying to retrieve by an External Id field, you need to specify the field, such as `/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Primary_subscription__c/ExternalIdField__c/0010l00000dd2`.